# How to convert string to Date/Time in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, time, date-conversion

Need to convert Strings of the form

```
1 Apr 17  0:01
1 Apr 17  0:09
```

to `Date/Time` form. Naturally, I tried both the `DateValue()` and `TimeValue()` functions, but when I use `DateValue()` on either string I get `4/1/17 12:00` ... in other words, I lose the time info.  If I try `TimeValue()`, I get `1/0/00 0:01` and `1/0/00 0:09` respectively - I lose the date.  How do I get both time and date in this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, DMY, Finish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem. The following worked for me . . .
Value in Cell A1 = 11-29-2022 14:07 IST
Value in Cell B1 = 11-29-2022 14:10 IST
To get the number of minutes elapsed between the 2,
Cell C1 has formula   = (VALUE(MID(B1, 1, 16)) - VALUE(MID(A1, 1, 16))) * 1440
which evaluates to 3

KS

Answer (score -1):

Just do...

```
DateValue() + TimeValue()
```

Comment: Huh I assumed the formats were distinct types, guess not.  It works, thanks!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.